# Backbone: How to update a model that isNew without fetching entire collection?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a form that `create` a model for a collection. That fires an `add` event to the collection. I have that binded to a method:

```
this.collection.bind('add', this.addOne, this)
```

fires...

```
addOne: function(tenant) {
   var self = this
   var collection = this.collection

   var view = new TenantView({model: tenant,collection:collection});
   self.$el.append(view.render().el);
}
```

The `create` syncs it to the database but, the new appended view still `isNew` to backbone since it hasn't fetched the collection and grabbed the id for the new model.

My question, how can I grab the synced model from the server (that has the id and isn't `isNew`) without fetching the entire collection **then** append it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `sync` event instead of `add`...

```
this.collection.bind('sync', this.addOne, this);
```

The `add` event gets fired *immediately* when calling `create`; but [`sync` gets fired once the server has responded to the create method, so it should include the correct model id](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-create).

You can also wait for the server's response, before adding the model to the collection -- to do that use `wait: true` in `create`'s options hash:  `collection.create({ ... }, { wait: true })`.

> Creating a model will cause an immediate "add" event to be triggered on the collection, as well as a "sync" event, once the model has been successfully created on the server.  Pass {wait: true} if you'd like to wait for the server before adding the new model to the collection.

Comment: When you fire create() it fires the add() and sync() so would be the same situation.

Comment: @delboud the difference is sync gets fired after the server responds, so it should be `isNew: false` and have the correct ID ... no?