# Backbone sync do not trigger

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

i've got errors and search through in StackOverFlow i found exactly same errors in below link

[Backbone: How to update a model that isNew without fetching entire collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13599744/backbone-how-to-update-a-model-that-isnew-without-fetching-entire-collection)

According to the comment , I changed `this.collection.bind('add', this.addOne, this)` to `.bind('sync',...).` 
My problem is that when  create event is occured , the sync is method is not at all fire.. .
I don't konw what the problem ...

Comment: The sync event is not guaranteed to fire - if you declare a success callback during any one of these operations, the sync event will not be triggered. Like other model events, it will bubble up to the collection as well.

Comment: yes it is right , i remove success method but the new appended view still isNew . How can i solve ?

Comment: Correction for you @CodeJack, `sync` -event is fired every single time the model is synchronized with the server. Check the source: http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html

Comment: What version of Backbone are you using? Backbone 1.0.0 doesn't support `bind` any longer. You'll have to use `on`. On the other hand, the `sync` -event was introduced in Backbone 0.9.0, so if your version is < 0.9.0 then it is never triggered

Comment: According to CodeJack comment,i removed success method and it trigger the `sync` method but the model id is still **undefined**